# Extending navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have created my Navigation Drawer activity. Everything works fine, but I would like to extend it to other activities. https://github.com/lupajz/bc/blob/master/app/src/com/kulturnepodujatia/DashboardActivity.java here is my Navigation Drawer Activity.

If I try to open another activity like for example :

```
public class Test extends DashboardActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I get errors :

```
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266): Process: com.kulturnepodujatia, PID: 19266
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kulturnepodujatia/com.kulturnepodujatia.Test}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07000b (com.kulturnepodujatia:id/frame_container) for fragment BaseFragment{64ababa0 #0 id=0x7f07000b}
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07000b (com.kulturnepodujatia:id/frame_container) for fragment BaseFragment{64ababa0 #0 id=0x7f07000b}
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
03-26 12:14:07.902: E/AndroidRuntime(19266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
```

Test acitivty has just a textivew in layout. The navigation drawer activity has this layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

    <!-- Framelayout pre zobrazovanie jednotlivých fragmentov -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview ako menu pre navDrawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:background="#2B2B2B"

        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Follow that tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention like this

```
public class Test extends DashboardActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu);
}
}
```

If you give onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) on Dashboard .You never need to mention over 
here....

Following one u have to give inside Manifest..

```
 <activity
                android:name=".Test"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
               >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the setContentView  in Test activity.  Your are already setting the contentview in Drawer Activity which has R.id.frame_container . so when you override  the onCreate your are setting the content view with different layout and when an Drawer itemb is selected it will fail since your trying to add fragment in R.id.frame_container.

Comment: Okay :) this was helpfull, now I have question. Can I modify this layout in Test activity ? Like remove toggle and just put back button there ?

Comment: Sure you can modify. You have full control of the view if you don't override with new view.

Comment: Okay I go that figured out. My question is how to access ActionBarDrawerToggle of first activity in another activity ?

Comment: If you have multiple activity then each activity have to extend to DashboardActivity , else you can use one activity and replace fragments when user selects the item in drawer list.

Comment: Yes, I know my question is how to access ActionBarToggle and replace it with back navigation arrow in action bar in extended activity classes ?